# Calculated field in Sql Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, calculated-columns

```
create proc PrAspnet_RolesGet
as

select  r.RoleId, r.RoleName, lr.RoleId as IsLoginetRole
from aspnet_Roles r

left join loginetRoles lr
on r.RoleId = lr.RoleId
```

The table loginetRoles contains one field - the RoleId. How can I replace the field IsLoginetRole from Guid value to bit value?

Comment: There is no boolean datatype. Only `bit`. What should the logic be for the conversion from `guid` to `bit`? You want to return `1` if `NOT NULL` and `0` if `NULL` or something?

Comment: Martin, Yeah. I want to return 1 if NOT NULL and 0 if NULL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT r.RoleId,
       r.RoleName,
       CAST(CASE
              WHEN lr.RoleId IS NULL THEN 0
              ELSE 1
            END AS BIT) AS IsLoginetRole
FROM   aspnet_Roles r
       LEFT JOIN loginetRoles lr
         ON r.RoleId = lr.RoleId
```